# Using singleton as a counter

Tags: python, singleton, python-2.6

I have an automation test, which uses function that creates screenshots to a folder. This function is called by multiple screenshot instances. On every test run, a new folder is created, so I don't care about counter reset. In order to reflect the order at which these screenshots are taken, I had to come up with names that could be sorted by order. This is my solution:

```
def make_screenshot_file(file_name):
    order = Counter().count
    test_suites_path = _make_job_directory()
    return make_writable_file(os.path.join(test_suites_path,'screenshot',file_name % order))


class Counter():
    __counter_instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        if Counter.__counter_instance is None:
            self.count = 1
            Counter.__counter_instance = self
        else: 
            Counter.__counter_instance.count += 1
            self.count =  Counter.__counter_instance.count
```

It works fine for me. But I keep thinking that there should be an easier way to solve this problem. Is there? And if singleton is the only way, could my code be optimized in any way?

Comment: This isn't actually a singleton at all. You create lots of `Counter` instances, and they all point to one "special instance". That's not the same as only having one instance.

Comment: Also, if you know enough about class attributes to create one called `__counter_instance`, why not just make a `count` class attribute?

Comment: @abarnert, sorry, I didn't understand your second comment. Could you show how it would look as the whole code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is simulate a global variable.

There is no good reason to do that. If you really want a global variable, make it explicitly a global variable.

You could create a simple `Counter` class that increments `count` by 1 each time you access it, and then create a global instance of it. But the standard library already gives you something like that for free, in [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), as DSM explains in a comment.

So:

```
import itertools

_counter = itertools.count()
def make_screenshot_file(file_name):
    order = next(_counter)
    test_suites_path = _make_job_directory()
    return make_writable_file(os.path.join(test_suites_path,'screenshot',file_name % order))
```

I'm not sure why you're so worried about how much storage or time this takes up, because I can't conceive of any program where it could possibly matter whether you were using 8 bytes or 800 for a single object you could never have more than one or, or whether it took 3ns or 3us to access it when you only do so a handful of times.

But if you *are* worried, as you can see from [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l3229), `count` is implemented in C, it's pretty memory-efficient, and if you don't do anything fancy with it, it comes down to basically a single `PyNumber_Add` to generate each number, which is a lot less than interpreting a few lines of code.

---

Since you asked, here's how you could radically simplify your existing code by using a `_count` class attribute instead of a `__counter_instance` class attribute:

```
class Counter():
    _count = 0
    def count(self):
        Counter._count += 1
        return Counter.count
```

Of course now you have to to `Counter().count()` instead of just `Counter().count`—but you can fix that trivially with `@property` if it matters.

It's worth pointing out that it's a really bad idea to use a classic class instead of a new-style class (by passing nothing inside the parens), and if you *do* want a classic class you should leave the parens off, and most Python programmers will associate the name `Counter` with the class `collections.Counter`, and there's no reason `count` couldn't be a `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`… at which point this is exactly Andrew T.'s answer. Which, as he points out, is much simpler than what you're doing, and no more or less Pythonic.

But really, all of this is no better than just making `_count` a module-level global and adding a module-level `count()` function that increments and returns it.

Answer (score 2):

why not just do

```
order = time.time()
```

or do something like

```
import glob #glob is used for unix like path expansion
order = len(glob.glob(os.path.join(test_suites_path,"screenshot","%s*"%filename))
```

Comment: Giving -1. May be the OP should not do it because it is an automation test. If this automation test runs from multiple machines at the same time, or probably from the same machine in different threads/processes at the same time, there are chances that he would get inconsistent results.

Comment: Because test_suites_path already has time in the name. I don't want to have two time name logic in the path.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Again the same argument applies. If you have the same time in both the file names, the data written in the file belong only to 1 file and not both of them :)

Answer (score 1):

Using static methods and variables. Not very pythonic, but simpler.

```
def make_screenshot_file(file_name):
    order = Counter.count() #Note the move of the parens
    test_suites_path = _make_job_directory()
    return make_writable_file(os.path.join(test_suites_path,'screenshot',file_name % order))

class Counter():
  count_n = 0

  @staticmethod
  def count():
    Counter.count_n += 1
    return Counter.count_n


print Counter.count()
print Counter.count()
print Counter.count()
print Counter.count()
print Counter.count()


atarzwell@freeman:~/src$ python so.py
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: You could use `C = itertools.count(1)` and then `order = next(C)`.

Comment: @Andrew T, So your solution would work much faster than mine, correct?

Comment: @Prostak: Who cares about how fast it counts to 5?

Comment: @Prostak: Also, whatever a "static class" is, you don't need one. Just make `C` a module-level global. (I know you've heard "globals are bad", but faking globals with things that don't look like globals and don't quite work but have all the same downsides isn't any better.)

Comment: @abarnert, just want to have it as lean as possible. The less memory it is using, the better. No memory leaks. Also, the faster, the better.

Comment: @abarnert, I like your answer the best so far. Very lean. Make it as a post and I'll give it to you.

Comment: @Prostak: Focusing on the memory and performance of things that don't matter is a very good way to make your code buggy, fragile, and unreadable without actually making anything smaller or faster. Whatever you use, it's going to take a few dozen bytes, not leak any memory, and run in nanoseconds. There is no advantage to be gained by worrying about it. And if there were, the only reasonable answer would be to code it in C or Cython, because the size and time used by a few bytecodes of Python dwarf the actual work involved.

Answer (score 0):

Well , you can use this solution, just make sure you never initialize the order kwarg!

Mutable Kwargs in function's work like classes global variables. And the value isn't reset to default between calls, as you might think at first!

```
def make_screenshot_file(file_name , order=[0]):
    order[0] = order[0] + 1
    test_suites_path = _make_job_directory()
    return make_writable_file(os.path.join(test_suites_path,'screenshot',file_name % order[0]))
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? This will return `1` every time. The value isn't "reset to default", but that's only because the value isn't ever changed. `order+=1` doesn't mutate the value `0`, it just binds a new value `0+1` to the local name `order`. Next time through, you'll again bind `0+1` to the local name `order`. And so on.

Comment: @abarnert , my bad... it only works on mutable objects , fixed the code. thanks for pointing my error.

Comment: Why would you write `order.append(order.pop()+1)` instead of just `order[0] += 1`?

Comment: you to fast !!!! Got confused with the UnboundLocalError issue , that is totally unrelated

Comment: @andsoa, when i tried your first answer, it didn't work. so i eliminated you. but then i tried your amended one. wow. it works. very impressed and learned a new trick. thanks! +1